# Creating a mask for natural earth R giving unexpected results

Tags: r, dplyr, geospatial

I am wanting to create a mask to color all parts of the image that are NOT within the specified land areas. I can get this to work successfully for two countries (e.g Burkina Faso and Nigeria). However, the same code does not work when I try a longer list of 9 countries in the same area. The error I am receiving is :
`Error in` [[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, attr(x, "sf_column"), value = list( : replacement has 2 rows, data has 1`

Being relatively new to GIS, I am not quite sure what the issue is or how to resolve it. I would really appreciate some help if people could offer some insight. The method I used was based on the accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266736/clip-spatial-polygon-by-world-map-in-r)

Relevant code is below. Thankyou in advance for anyone who is able to help.

### This code works perfectly fine

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266736/clip-spatial-polygon-by-world-map-in-r
x_coord = c(-20,-20,27,27)
y_coord = c(-1,28,28,-1)

# Create rectalgular polygon for a mask (slightly bigger than the image)
polygon <-  cbind(x_coord, y_coord) %>%
  st_linestring() %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  st_sfc(crs = 4326, check_ring_dir = TRUE) %>%
  st_sf() %>%
  st_wrap_dateline()

land = ne_countries(scale = "medium", 
             returnclass = "sf") %>% 
     filter(admin %in% c("Nigeria", "Burkina Faso"))
    #filter(admin %in% c("Niger", "Burkina Faso", "Nigeria", "Mali", "Chad", "Mauritania",
    #              "Gambia", "Senegal", "Guinea", "Cameroon"))


# Get the difference between the bounding box and the area I want to plot
# This works fine when using only two countries 
land = st_union(land)
polygon_land_diff = st_difference(polygon, land)

# Plot the data 
plot(st_geometry(land))
plot(st_geometry(polygon), add=TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(polygon_land_diff),add=TRUE, col="green")
```

### This code produces an error and I am not sure how to resolve it. The only difference is the number of countries selected

```
x_coord = c(-20,-20,27,27)
y_coord = c(-1,28,28,-1)

# Create rectalgular polygon for a mask (slightly bigger than the image)
polygon <-  cbind(x_coord, y_coord) %>%
  st_linestring() %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  st_sfc(crs = 4326, check_ring_dir = TRUE) %>%
  st_sf() %>%
  st_wrap_dateline()

land = ne_countries(scale = "medium", 
             returnclass = "sf") %>% 
    filter(admin %in% c("Niger", "Burkina Faso", "Nigeria", "Mali", "Chad", "Mauritania",
                  "Gambia", "Senegal", "Guinea", "Cameroon"))


# get the difference between the bounding box and the area I want to plot
# not quite working. The rror occurs when running  `polygon_land_diff = st_difference(polygon, land)`

land = st_union(land)
polygon_land_diff = st_difference(polygon, land)

# Plot the data 
plot(st_geometry(land))
plot(st_geometry(polygon), add=TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(polygon_land_diff),add=TRUE, col="green")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`st_difference()` is generic function and I guess it faild to choice appropriate method at your latter case. (I didn't read source code, this is an estimate.)
Maybe it choice not `sfc` but `sf` method. (because `Polygon` is class `sf`)
you can get desired output by making polygon `sfc` class or using `sf:::st_difference.sfc` directly.
Below is an example;

```
x_coord = c(-20,-20,27,27)
y_coord = c(-1,28,28,-1)


polygon <-  cbind(x_coord, y_coord) %>%
  st_linestring() %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  st_sfc(crs = 4326, check_ring_dir = TRUE)# %>%  # keep sfc class
#  st_sf() %>%
#  st_wrap_dateline()

land = ne_countries(scale = "medium", 
                    returnclass = "sf") %>% 
  filter(admin %in% c("Niger", "Burkina Faso", "Nigeria", "Mali", "Chad", "Mauritania",
                      "Gambia", "Senegal", "Guinea", "Cameroon"))

land = st_union(land)
polygon_land_diff = st_difference(polygon, land)

# Plot the data 
plot(st_geometry(land))
plot(st_geometry(polygon), add=TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(polygon_land_diff),add=TRUE, col="green")
```

[image]